# Image from UIIMagePicker gets rotated

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I need to get the image from uiimagepicker and need to show it in a uiimageview.It is working perfectly in simulator.But on device,the image from uiimagepicker is rotated.How to resolve this?

Comment: re-rotate it to its original

Answer (score 0):

This problem occur due to portrait/landscape orientation of the cell phone camera. Re-rotate your image like

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [sourceImage CGImage];

UIImage *rotatedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

OR try something like this

```
static inline double radians (double degrees) {return degrees * M_PI/180;}
UIImage* rotate(UIImage* src, UIImageOrientation orientation)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(src.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (orientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(90));
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(-90));
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        // NOTHING
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(90));
    }

    [src drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix Orientation of image before use it.
Use below extension to fix UIImage orientation.

```
extension UIImage {
    
    /// Fix image orientaton to protrait up
    func fixedOrientation() -> UIImage? {
        guard imageOrientation != UIImage.Orientation.up else {
            // This is default orientation, don't need to do anything
            return self.copy() as? UIImage
        }
        
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else {
            // CGImage is not available
            return nil
        }
        
        guard let colorSpace = cgImage.colorSpace, let ctx = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(size.width), height: Int(size.height), bitsPerComponent: cgImage.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue) else {
            return nil // Not able to create CGContext
        }
        
        var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        
        switch imageOrientation {
        case .down, .downMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: size.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi)
        case .left, .leftMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 2.0)
        case .right, .rightMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / -2.0)
        case .up, .upMirrored:
            break
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
        
        // Flip image if needed to, this is to prevent flipped image
        switch imageOrientation {
        case .upMirrored, .downMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
        case .leftMirrored, .rightMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.height, y: 0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
        case .up, .down, .left, .right:
            break
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
        
        ctx.concatenate(transform)
        
        switch imageOrientation {
        case .left, .leftMirrored, .right, .rightMirrored:
            ctx.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.height, height: size.width))
        default:
            ctx.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
            break
        }
        
        guard let newCGImage = ctx.makeImage() else { return nil }
        return UIImage.init(cgImage: newCGImage, scale: 1, orientation: .up)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let fixedImage = myImage.fixedOrientation()
```

Comment: This is totally unnecessary. OP is probably saving the image as PNG and discarding its orientation. All is needed is to use JPEG instead of PNG. Btw why not simply `return self` instead of `return self.copy() as? UIImage`?